# Electron: Prevent throttling renderer processes

Tags: javascript, electron

I have an Electron app that receives push notifications. How this works is, I spin up threads like so from the Main process:

```js
const Engine = fork(path.join(__dirname, 'engine.js'), [], {
  stdio: ['pipe', 'pipe', 'pipe', 'ipc']
})
```

These threads bind to a number of services that send push notifications through a Websocket. This all works fine: I log the timing of the push notifications and I can see it is nearly instant, so these threads are spinning just fine.

Next, these threads surface the push notifications to my UI by sending a message through a Websocket to a Renderer process (created as a `BrowserWindow`). I consume this like so:

```js
socket.onmessage = m => {
  const { event, payload } = JSON.parse(m.data) // { event: "name", payload: {...} }
  console.log("EVENT:", event)
  switch (event) {
    case "push-notification": showNotification(payload); break;
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

This also works fine whenever the Renderer process is in the foreground. However, left in the background for longer than a few minutes, it seems to get throttled, as I can see the timestamped logs from the forked process (`Engine` above) are a good 30s to several minutes separated from the matching `"EVENT:"` logs from the renderer process.

To troubleshoot I had the Renderer process check an interval:

```js
let atom = (new Date()).getTime()
window.setInterval(() => {
  if ((new Date()).getTime() > (atom + 60 * 1000)) {
    // clock out of sync
    console.error("CLOCK OUT OF SYNC")
  }
  console.log("Tick. Tock.")
  atom = (new Date()).getTime()
}, 1000)
```

When I leave the app in the background for some time and then open it again, I can see the `Tick. Tock.` messages get further and further apart until they stop altogether, and then some seconds after foregrounding it I get the `CLOCK OUT OF SYNC` error, indicating the interval had paused until I foregrounded the app again.

I found a few mentions of this across the web like [this thread](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/4317), and tried the following:

```js
// before running any renderers
app.commandLine.appendSwitch('disable-renderer-backgrounding');
app.commandLine.appendSwitch('disable-background-timer-throttling');
app.commandLine.appendSwitch('disable-backgrounding-occluded-windows');
powerSaveBlocker.start('prevent-app-suspension');

// when making any BrowserWindow:
new BrowserWindow({
  ...
  webPreferences: {
   backgroundThrottling: false,
   ...
  },
  ...
})

// in my renderer process in a random JS script
const context = new AudioContext()
const source = context.createBufferSource()
source.connect(context.destination)
source.start(0)
```

I'm on Electron 20.0.0 and so far nothing has worked. Is there any way I can keep the renderer process running full speed with no delays while in the background?

The most I can delay is 10-15 seconds, and would also accept a solution for waking up the renderer process/unthrottling it manually using the main process. To that end I've tried the following:

```js
// where win is a BrowserWindow
win.focus()
await sleep(120); // Promise-based sleep, appr. 2 JS frames
win.minimize()
```

Which unfortunately did not do the trick either.